# Unable to read GIT commitId, Branch and URL from Jenkins environment variables

Tags: git, jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

I am getting "null" values from below variables, when I am accessing from my build.gradle. GITSCM values will be null only when code is cloned into the Jenkins Workspace as part of git checkout stage in Jenkinsfile.

System.getenv('GIT_BRANCH')

System.getenv('GIT_COMMIT')

System.getenv('GIT_URL')

```
stage ('Check Out') {
            steps {
                echo 'Check-Out code from SCM'
                echo "Git Name : ${env.APP_NAME}"
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
                    branches: [[name: '**/${BRANCH}']],
                    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                    extensions: [],
                    submoduleCfg: [],
                    userRemoteConfigs: [[
                            credentialsId: 'GITHUB_KEY' ,
                            url: "git@github.com:tools-org/${env.APP_NAME}"]]])
            }
        }
```

Can you please assist how to read checkout block to fetch GIT(CommitId, branch, repo) details in build.gradle ?

Answer (score 1):

These should be available as `env.BRANCH_NAME`, `env.GIT_COMMIT_ID` and `env.GIT_URL` respectively.

You can issue e.g. `sh "printenv | sort"` to see all the variables.

Comment: ..when I am printing it.
```echo "${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
                echo "${env.GIT_COMMIT_ID}"
                echo "${env.GIT_URL}"
```
It is showing as null

Comment: I am using regular pipeline job not the multi branch pipeline. is there any way of accessing the GIT variables in the regular pipeline job ?

Comment: how to read checkout block defined in pipeline script to fetch GIT(CommitId, branch, repo) details in init.gradle

Answer (score 0):

I could fetch the GIT branch name in init.gradle using below code.

```
 def branchStdOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'name-rev', '--name-only', 'HEAD'
        standardOutput = branchStdOut
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try `def someVar = checkout scm`.

The GIT_COMMIT, GIT_BRANCH, etc should be within the defined variable.